# How to kill a process using the window's name of this process with python or bat

Tags: python, process, kill-process

Now i have several same process activated in my system. Besides, although these process have same process name, they have different window title name. And sometimes i want to kill a specific window. If i kill process using process name, i may kill a process which should be alive. How can i solve this? How to kill a process using the window's name of this process? (Python or Bat if fine)

for example, if i kill process by process name:

```
import psutil

PROCNAME = 'server'

def kill():
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name == PROCNAME:
            proc.kill()
```

However, now i want to kill process by window's title name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have found the solution. i can use bat command like this:

```
taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq titleName"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [taskkill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx)

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /im PROCNAME.exe")
```

Comment: thx, but i want to kill by windowtitle instead of process name